# Data Studio search function, Set two date filters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I have two questions.

1. Can I search for characters in Data Studio and have the results show up in a chart based on the characters I searched for?
2. In Data Studio, can I select two date range filters and select period A and period B to see only the data for that period?
   The two periods are not fixed, so I would like to select them through the period filter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds as though both of your questions can be answered by filters, though it does depend on how you want to search by characters.

Firstly to address point 2 - you can have filters that subset each other, for example you can have a filter for `year` and a filter for `month`, if you first select a `year` the `month` filter will update to show only the available months from the data, I believe this is what you are asking.

For point 1, you can use the same approach to filter by strings and DataStudio provides a search functionality on the filter, so you filter quickly to what you need. Any linked charts would then update based on the value/s in this filter.

Answer (score 0):

Only trying to help with question no 2.

I had a similar problem. apparently No. you cant use two date filters in data studio. 
what you can do, is turn one of your date fields into a "filter", and then select from a list of categories, as you would do with, lets say, a City filter. that way, you can filter for one of the date ranges, using a date range box, and filter the other dates, using the filter box.